# getting cannot find error in java even though the classes are declared

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

```
public class Video {

    String videoName;
    boolean checkout;
    int rating;

    public Video(){

    }

    public Video(String name)
    {
        videoName=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return videoName;
    }
    public void doCheckout()
    {

            System.err.println("Video "+'"'+ getName()+'"' +" checked out successfully.");

    }
    public void doReturn()
    {
        checkout=true;
        System.err.println("Video "+'"'+ getName()+'"' +" returned successfully.");

    }
    public void receiveRating(int rating)
    {
        this.rating=rating;
    }
    public int getRating()
    {
        return rating;
    }
    public boolean getCheckout()
    {
        return checkout;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class VideoStore {

    Video store[];
    public VideoStore() {

        store=new Video[5];
    }
    public void addVideo(String name)
    {

        store[0]=new Video(name);
        System.err.println("Video "+'"'+store[0].getName()+'"'+" added successfully");
    }
    public void doCheckout(String name)
    {
        if(store[0].videoName.equals(name))
        {
            store[0].doCheckout();
        }
    }
    public void doReturn(String name)
    {
        if(store[0].videoName.equals(name))
        {
            store[0].doReturn();
        }
    }
    public void receiveRating(String name, int rating) {

        if(store[0].videoName.equals(name))
        {
            store[0].receiveRating(rating);
        }
        System.err.println("Rating "+'"'+store[0].getRating()+'"'+" has been mapped to the Video ''"+store[0].getName()+'"');

    }
    public void listInventory() {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Video Name | Checkout Status | Rating");
        System.out.println(store[0].getName()+"|" +store[0].getCheckout()+ "|"+ store[0].getRating());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VideoLaucher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        VideoStore videoStore=new VideoStore();
        do {
                System.out.println("MAIN MENU \n=========");
                System.out.println("1. Add Videos:");
                System.out.println("2. Check Out Video:");
                System.out.println("3. Return Video:");
                System.out.println("4. Receive Rating:");
                System.out.println("5. List Inventory:");
                System.out.println("6. Exit:");
                System.out.print("Enter your choice(1..6): ");

                choice=input.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter the name of the video you want to add: ");
                    videoStore.addVideo(input.next());
                    break;
                case 2:
                        System.out.print("Enter the name of the video you want to check out: ");
                        videoStore.doCheckout(input.next());
                        break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the video you want to Return:");
                    videoStore.doReturn(input.next());;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Enter the name of the video you want to Rate: ");
                    videoStore.receiveRating(input.next(), input.nextInt());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    videoStore.listInventory();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.err.println("Enter ...!! Thanks for using the application");
                    System.exit(1);
                    break;
                }
        }while(!(choice==6));       
                input.close();
    }
}
```

when I try to compile `VideoStore.java` and `VideoLaucher.java` I am getting the following errors

```
[neo@EDI Practice]$ javac VideoStore.java
VideoStore.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Video store[];
        ^
  symbol:   class Video
  location: class VideoStore
VideoStore.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                store=new Video[5];
                          ^
  symbol:   class Video
  location: class VideoStore
VideoStore.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                store[0]=new Video(name);
                             ^
  symbol:   class Video
  location: class VideoStore
3 errors
```

Comment: Compile `Video.java` first.

Comment: Where are you keeping these files, and how are you compiling them. Often javac will compile source files if they're required. It is not always perfect so you can include *all* of the source files when you compile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javac can't find class that is in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524949/javac-cant-find-class-that-is-in-the-same-directory)

Comment: You should compile the file that has the *main* method. This is the VideoLaucher.java file. Then it actually compiles for me if all files are in the same directory. I get a crash when I run the program after inputting a movie though.